# How do I dynamically allocate an array of vectors using "new" in C++?

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

This is for a hash table lab so I will need to be able to add entries to the vectors. Also, how would I go about accessing entries with this format?

Comment: Questions about homework problems need to show what effort you have made so far in solving them and specifically describe where you got stuck in order to be on topic for StackOverflow. Exploring these topics yourself is an important part of learning how to program.

Comment: Thanks @seaotternerd. This time all I needed was just the code to allocate the array but I will definitely keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Same way you would dynamically allocate an array of anything else:

```
std::vector<T>* array = new std::vector<T>[42];
```

Although it's a lot simpler to just use a `vector` of `vector`s instead:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T> > array(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array can be created as Barry mentioned. You can access the information in the same way as any other:

```
std::vector<int>* numbers = new std::vector<int>[5]; // 5 vectors of ints
// iterate through all elements
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    numbers[i].push_back(i * 2);
    cout << numbers[i][0] << endl;
    //              *  ^
    // * = array index
    // ^ = vector index
}
```